# Not all identifier properties can be found in the ResultSetMapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I dont really what means the error that I put in the title:

This is how I build my query builder :

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('etablissement.numetb AS id')
        ->addSelect("concat('Etablissement ', etablissement.numetb) AS name")
        ->addSelect("etablissement.raisonsoc AS description")
        ->addSelect("etablissement.datcreation AS datcreation")
        ->addSelect("11 AS type")
        ->addSelect("identity(etablissement.statut) AS statut")
        ->from('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'etablissement')
        ->orderBy('datcreation', 'DESC');
```

My repository is a service not linked to an entity (if it can help).

Can you explain what means this error ? and how to solve it ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and how i have to write the query builder to make it work :

Doing this makes the error going away :

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    **->select('etablissement')
    ->addSelect('etablissement.numetb AS id')**
    ->addSelect("concat('Etablissement ', etablissement.numetb) AS name")
    ->addSelect("etablissement.raisonsoc AS description")
    ->addSelect("etablissement.datcreation AS datcreation")
    ->addSelect("11 AS type")
    ->addSelect("identity(etablissement.statut) AS statut")
    ->from('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'etablissement')
    ->orderBy('datcreation', 'DESC');
```

Comment: For anyone who can't see it, "Doing this" is selecting the entire entity in addition to selecting its properties.

Answer (score 15):

For me solution was setting paginator's output walkers to false.

```
$paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);
```

Comment: Confirmed this works for me.  This behaviour is also described at [PHP Beginner to Advanced: Symfony and Doctrine: Pagination](https://phpbeginnertoadvanced.blogspot.com.au/2015/11/symfony-and-doctrine-pagination-with-dql.html). However, I can't find what this actually does and why it has to be disabled. The accepted answer is also correct where a selecting of the whole entity, in addition to it's properties, will prevent the error.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This does not work if your query has a HAVING clause

Answer (score 9):

For me solution was to change **select** method to **addSelect**, i.e.:

```
$this->em->createQueryBuilder()->select('e.id')
```

to

```
$this->em->createQueryBuilder()->addSelect('e.id')
```

Comment: setUseOutputWalkers(false) causes the paginator count method to return 0, while this solution keeps the correct count.

Answer (score 4):

This error means that you have to select in your query all identifiers of your entity. Identifiers are the fields with a @id annotation in your entity.

Comment: I just have one and it is etablissement.numetb